# Inconsistency with text describing post status

Tags: bug, design, search, question-lists

Questions in the ["Top Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) list contain user name without "by" word:

> [image: noby]

But posts in the ["Search results"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user) contain "by" in same situation:

> [image: by]

I think it should be written the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, I don't think this is a bug.

When you search for a question or answer, you don't care when it was last edited, you want only to know when it was asked or answered. So the search results are showing exactly this: time when the post has been posted, and this is always done **by** the author of the post.

On the other hand, questions list are sorted by activity. What matters there is when the last event happened to the question, be it an edit, reopening, bounty, etc, and who did it. This can be done by bunch of different people, not  just the post author.

So suppose a question was asked by Bob, then edited by Alice. If the question list would show "modified 1 hour ago by Alice", it would be confusing. People might think it means Alice wrote the question, and it was modified one hour ago.

I see it as separating the data into "what" and "who":

> [image]

Also, some actions are not explicit, i.e. have no visible change on the question, for example reopening or bounty. Nothing was actually modified in the question itself, so having a "by" would also feel wrong.

Comment: Is using `by` in context with `modified` means that post modified by OP only? English is not my native language, so this is not obviously for me.

Comment: @alexolut same here, and maybe I let my experience on the site affect my way of thinking, but yes to me adding the "by" would mean it was done by the person who actually wrote the post.

Comment: I disagree that it would be confusing. Your separation of "what" and "who" isn't separated at all, what is shown is the "who" of that specific "what", which makes perfect sense with the preposition "by".

Comment: @Cai fair enough, the separation is mostly in my own mind I guess, as I got used to it. But still, good chance this is the reason for omitting the "by" from questions lists in the first place.